# Images and CSS effect not showing

Tags: theming

Hello I'm using Drupal 6 and I've successfully finished with the site. However, after I uploaded the site to the server, I realised the the header image which is the logo is not showing even though the path is correct in the theme logo path.

Also there is a slide show which was made with Dynamic Display Block module and its images does not show up even though their path is present and correct.

The css style I applied to the three column under the DD Block is also not showing.

This still persists even if I change theme.

Does anyone know what's wrong under the hood?

Thank you

Comment: check file permissions and double check if file exists in specified location

Comment: I have crosschecked all permission especially uploaded files with respect to the problem at hand. All files exists in their respective directories and the path to each is very correct, yet problem still persists. :(

Comment: if you request the path of the logo image directly in the address bar of your browser, does it show up ?

Comment: It mustn't be possible for people to do that due security purposes. However, I did that anyway, and it wasn't successful.  It returned:  

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

Also, you cannot see the images when you use firebug debugger!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check the permission of "sites" and "files" folders. You cannot access to the folder.

I think something happened when you uploaded the website. Usually I do a fresh installation of drupal then I upload the files inside "all" folder and the files insidethe "files" folder inside "default". In the end through Backup and Migrate module I upload the db.

It must be a permission problem if you see the images there.

Let me know.

Comment: I did all that, just as you do yours, and yet problem still persists! :(

Comment: Awesome! It worked! It's from the hosting company! I spoke to them, and I got them fix it!